# EF: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types

Tags: entity-framework

Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Models:

`

```
[Table("Employees")]
public class Employee : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? AbsenceId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AbsenceId")]
    public virtual Absence Absence { get; set; }
}

[Table("Absences")]
public class Absence : Entity
{
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public int? SubstituteId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubstituteId")]
    public virtual Employee Substitute { get; set; }
}
```

`

The Employee have a Absence that can have a Employee that is not same Employee that have a Absence mentioned.

Any solution for this case?

Answer (score 6):

Well, first of all.. You do not need to specify ForeignKey when you are following the Entity Framework conventions.  By convention, EF will reocognize the fact that your Navigation property is called Foo and your ForeignKey will be called FooId.

However, the real problem is that you are attempting to create a 1:1 association between two entities and EF does not support associations like this.

EF only supports 1:1 associations with shared primary keys, that is where both tables have the same primary key and one table's PK is a FK to the other table's PK.

If you think about this, it makes sense.  There is no native 1:1 relationship in SQL that does not have a shared primary key.  If you add a FK in one table to the other, it creates a 1:Many.  You can simulate a 1:1 by creating a unique constraint on the FK but EF does not support constraints.

Looking at your model.  Do you really want a 1:1 anyways?  Can an employee really only have a single absence?  Ever?  Probably not.  You probably want Absence to be a 1:Many.  So remove AbsenceId and change Absence to:

```
public virtual List<Absence> Absences { get; set; }
```